# how to calculating Total working hours between two dates

Tags: sql-server

```
Emp_id      Logdate
1        2016-05-04 11:10
1        2016-05-04 12:20
1        2016-05-04 13:10
1        2016-05-04 17:45
1        2016-05-04 18:10
1        2016-05-05 02:10      
2        2016-05-04 13:10
2        2016-05-04 14:20
2        2016-05-04 15:10
2        2016-05-04 17:45
2        2016-05-04 18:10
2        2016-05-04 20:10
```

From the above table how to calculating total working per day  .  thing is employee I'd 1 is entering at 11.00 Am  and leave at next day of 2.00 PM .
From this how to calculate working hours for all the employee....

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? What's your expected output for employees 1 & 2?

Comment: Is this a min/max question or an in/out question?

Comment: Does the employee have breaks?

Comment: Except first and last entry ,others are considered as break

Comment: Version is SQL server 2014

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
Declare @t TABLE (Emp_id INT,  Logdate Varchar(30))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1  ,'2016-05-04 11:10'),
(1  ,'2016-05-04 12:20'),
(1  ,'2016-05-04 13:10'),
(1  ,'2016-05-04 17:45'),
(1  ,'2016-05-04 18:10'),
(1  ,'2016-05-05 02:10'),   
(2  ,'2016-05-04 13:10'),
(2  ,'2016-05-04 14:20'),
(2  ,'2016-05-04 15:10'),
(2  ,'2016-05-04 17:45'),
(2  ,'2016-05-04 18:10'),
(2  ,'2016-05-04 20:10')
```

**Query**

```
; WITH X AS(
Select Emp_id 
      , CONVERT(DATETIME, Logdate) AS Logdate
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_id
                     ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, Logdate) ) rn
from @t
 ),Y AS(
SELECT Emp_id
      ,Logdate LogDateTime
      ,CASE WHEN rn % 2 =1 THEN 0
            WHEN rn % 2 =0 THEN 1
       END [InOut]
       ,CONVERT(DATE, Logdate) Logdate 
       ,rn
FROM X 
),WorkingHours AS (
SELECT Y.Emp_id
      ,Y.LogDateTime  TimeIn
      ,YY.LogDateTime TimeOut
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Y.LogDateTime,YY.LogDateTime) *1.00 / 60.0 HoursWorked
      ,Y.Logdate      DateWoked
FROM Y
LEFT JOIN Y AS YY ON Y.Emp_id = YY.Emp_id
                 AND Y.rn = YY.rn - 1
                 AND Y.InOut = 0
WHERE Y.InOut <> 1)
Select Emp_id
      ,CAST(ROUND(SUM(HoursWorked) ,2) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) TotalHours 
      ,DateWoked
FROM WorkingHours
GROUP BY Emp_id, DateWoked
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ Emp_id ║ TotalHours ║ DateWoked  ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║      1 ║ 13.75      ║ 2016-05-04 ║
║      2 ║ 5.75       ║ 2016-05-04 ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Except first and last entry others are considered as break.. So we have to take only first and last entry  as TOTALWORKING HOURS. Others   calculated as BREAK DURATION..